# Markdown attribute causes translate pipe to not translate the string

Tags: html, angular, markdown, ngx-translate

I've got this paragraph in angular component that contains markdown attribute. Sometimes, but not always the markdown causes translation pipe to not translate the title.description string:

`<p class="someClass" markdown>{{tile.description | translate}}</p>`

There is no related errors in the console.

I've tried exact same code but without markdown and it worked in the same component. Also tried wrapping translation in  tag.

How can I solve this problem and what causes it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to solve this problem:

```
<p class="someClass" [innerHTML]="tile.description | translate | markdown"></p>
```